# Генерация xml по xsd схеме

Tags: xml, java

Существуют ли библиотеки, реализующие возможность генерации xml по xsd схеме?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Каким образом можно получить в общем случае XML из XSD? К тому же, строго говоря, XSD сама по себе является XML-документом.

Comment: Кроме того, непонятно, о каком языке идёт речь.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я зашел на этот сайт по ссылке "задать вопрос по Java" и потому не уточнил язык. А имею в виду вот что: раз xsd описывает структуру xml документа, то логично предположить, что на основании этого описания можно сформировать шаблон xml (с пустыми или дефолтными значениями).

Comment: А зачем вообще такое нужно? Если вы хотите генерировать XML с данными, то можете использовать JAXB, чтобы сгенерировать код для этого из XSD-схемы.

Comment: Генерация XML-документа по схеме может очень помочь в тестировании кода, который занимается парсингом XML.

Answer (score 2):

такую задачу я решил с **org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions;**

Answer (score 0):

В Visual Studio есть [обозреватель XML-схем](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc716766.aspx), который может генерировать образец документа XML по схеме XSD. Для этого нужно:

- открыть схему
- выбрать корневой узел
- сделать правый клик мышкой
- выбрать создание XML

Кроме того, в .NET есть XmlSampleGenerator API. Подробнее здесь: [Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Взгляните на [xsd2inst (Schema to Instance Tool)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#xsd2inst), в том числе на их [исходники](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/xsd2inst/).

> Prints an XML instance from the specified global element using the specified schema.

Comment: Кажется, такой программы больше нет...