# Проверить правильность построения xsd схемы и создания для нее xml

Tags: xml, xsd

Я новичок в xsd и xml. Я написала схему по заданию, но при попытке проверить ее через онлайн-переводчики, пишут: The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType' element is not supported in this context.

Прошу помощи в указании где ошибка и желательно как ее исправить. Так же буду признательна ответу на вопрос, как сделать для xsd схемы xml, которую будет проверять xsd.

Да, и еще вопрос, как проверить что будет выдаваться при заполнении xml специальными значениями, и запуске xsd на проверку xml? Возможно ли это?

Вот мой xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="CupboardRequest">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Запрос данных о шкафчике</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Employee" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="CupboardResponse">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Ответ о содержимом</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Employee" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="Cupboard" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <!-- Шкафчик -->
                        <xsd:element name="CupboardMini" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
                        <xsd:element name="CupboardMaxi" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>      

     <xsd:complexType name="CupboardMini">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation> маленький ящик </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- маленькие предметы -->
            <xsd:element name="MiniItem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>  
            <!-- большой предмет -->
            <xsd:element name="MaxiItem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="CupboardMaxi">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation> большой ящик </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- маленькие предметы -->
            <xsd:element name="MiniItem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <!-- большие предметы -->
            <xsd:element name="MaxiItem" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3"/>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Items">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation> предмет </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- id причины дефолта/снятия дефолта -->
            <xsd:element name="Simple" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <!-- windows login голосующего -->
            <xsd:element name="Book" type="bookType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="bookType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- Описания типов -->

    <xsd:simpleType name="EmployeeName">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="3"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,20}$"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="StatusType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="4"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="6" />
            <xsd:pattern value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{4,6}$"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном проблема в `<!-- маленькие предметы -->` и в `<!-- большие предметы -->`

Вот так проходит чек вот [здесь](http://xsd2xml.com/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="CupboardRequest">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Запрос данных о шкафчике</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Employee" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="CupboardResponse">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Ответ о содержимом</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Employee" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="Cupboard" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <!-- Шкафчик -->
                            <xsd:element name="CupboardMini" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
                            <xsd:element name="CupboardMaxi" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="CupboardMini">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>маленький ящик</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <!-- маленькие предметы -->
                <xsd:element name="MiniItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <!-- большой предмет -->
                <xsd:element name="MaxiItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="CupboardMaxi">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>большой ящик</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <!-- маленькие предметы -->
                <xsd:element name="MiniItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <!-- большие предметы -->
                <xsd:element name="MaxiItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Items" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="Items">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>предмет</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- id причины дефолта/снятия дефолта -->
            <xsd:element name="Simple" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <!-- windows login голосующего -->
            <xsd:element name="Book" type="bookType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="bookType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- Описания типов -->

    <xsd:simpleType name="EmployeeName">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="3"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,20}$"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="StatusType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="4"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{4,6}$"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

А про генерацию [вот есть ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18281/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-xml-%D0%BF%D0%BE-xsd-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5) либо [здесь](https://devutilsonline.com/xsd-xml/generate-xml-from-xsd) замечательно все генерируется.